# Compilation issue on mac

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I'm working on a project on windows. But I copied the `c++`and `h` files and created a makefile just for it on mac. But when compiling, I received this messages. And I don't know where it comes from.

```sh
src/main.cpp:6:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_shared<WindowHandler, int, int>' requested here
        auto win = std::make_shared<WindowHandler>(900, 600);
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3585:9: note: candidate constructor [with _A0 = int, _A1 = int] not viable: expects an l-value
      for 2nd argument
        __shared_ptr_emplace(_Alloc __a, _A0& __a0, _A1& __a1)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3580:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were
      provided
        __shared_ptr_emplace(_Alloc __a, _A0& __a0)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3590:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 3 were
      provided
        __shared_ptr_emplace(_Alloc __a, _A0& __a0, _A1& __a1, _A2& __a2)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3566:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__a', but 3 arguments
      were provided
    __shared_ptr_emplace(_Alloc __a)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3559:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1
      argument, but 3 were provided
class __shared_ptr_emplace
```

This is the makefile

```
SRC     =   main.cpp            \
            Cells.cpp           \
            WindowHandler.cpp

OBJ     =   $(foreach source, $(SRC), src/$(source:.cpp=.o))
NAME    =   MazeGenerator
CFLAGS  =   -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -Isrc/include
LDFLAGS =   -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CC      =   g++
LD      =   g++

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

I tried to replace my smart pointer by an instance creation and it works, but why isn't it working with a smart pointer.

This is the places where I replaced

```cpp
int main()
{
    //auto win = std::make_shared<WindowHandler>(900, 600);
    WindowHandler *win = new WindowHandler(900, 600);
    win->start();
    return 0;
}
```

and in the header

```cpp
class WindowHandler
{
public:
    WindowHandler(int, int);
    ~WindowHandler() {delete _cells;};
    void start();
    sf::RenderWindow& getWindow() { return *_window; };

private:
    sf::RenderWindow *_window;
    sf::Event event;
    //std::shared_ptr<Cell> _cells = std::make_shared<Cell>();
    Cell *_cells;
};
```

Comment: The errors come from the code. Pity we can't see any of it. Someone here might be able to explain the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 then why it's compiling perfectly on windows ? I didn't change anything

Comment: @samuelpotter That's not uncommon. In this particular case, I suspect that your `WindowHandler` constructor takes its arguments as non-const references, for some inexplicable reason. (Allowing the binding of a non-const reference to a temporary is a very annoying Microsoft "extension".)

Comment: Different compilers have subtly different interpretations of the language rules. You could have something marginal where two compilers disagree on interpretation, one of the compilers could have an exception that allows for otherwise illegal syntax, or you could have just tripped over a bug in one of the compilers. Without code there really isn't much we can do to help. Fortunately, you should be able to reproduce this error in  a fairly small piece of code.

Comment: Try to move constructor values(900 and 600) to separate variables and pass them to make_shared.

Comment: @Borys I tried this, and get a segv.
```c++
        int x = 900;
 int y = 600;
 std::shared_ptr<WindowHandler> win = std::make_shared<WindowHandler> (x, y);
```

Comment: @samuelpotter try to use another compiler, for example, clang(apple clang must be distributed with xcode). And does  $_cells initialized? Maybe segv because of nullptr deletion.

Comment: Don't know why the compiler complained over the commented-out code. There might be something deeper going on elsewhere that leaves the compiler confused. Looks like `WindowHandler *win = new WindowHandler(900, 600);` could be `WindowHandler win(900, 600);` and eliminate the pointer shared or not. A variable named `_cells` implies there is more than one `Cell`. Consider a `std::vector` as a replacement.